# Making a Pod available only to Tests, and not Sources

Tags: ios, swift, testing, cocoapods

I am kind of confused as to why I am getting this result. The following is my `Podfile`

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do
  pod 'SwiftLint'

  target 'ProjectTests' do
      inherit! :search_paths
      pod 'Kakapo'
  end

end
```

In this case, I expect `Kakapo` to only be available to my `ProjectTests` files. However, I am able to import it in `Project` source files, which is not what I expected, and I don't want it to be available there. Can anyone shed some light as to why this is the case, and how I can fix this?

Comment: What's the problem with it being available workspace-wide? It's not like you *have to* import it in your source code files, ha.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I don't have to, yes. I'm just curious why this is the case since I put the pod inside ProjectTests...

Comment: Does it fully work this way or is it only importable but then not actually doing anything?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Can be imported, and works there as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do
  pod 'SwiftLint' 
end

target 'ProjectTests' do
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'Kakapo'  
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! for some reason this also doesn't solve the problem.. I think I'll just accept the fact that it is also available in Sources, no problems

Comment: In my project I have multiple targets and Im using some additional pods for couple of targets. And it’s working completely fine. I don’t think UnitTest target will behave differently. It's weird if it's not working.

Comment: I just did a quick test by adding an additional pod for test target,. and it worked perfectly as expected. Let me know if you want a sample code.